# Spring Boot 2.2.6 failed in WildFly20

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm exactly not sure what went wrong, but I'm sure previously it used to work. All of sudden spring boot application started failing saying below error

```
23:21:24,728 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0048: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener
    at org.jboss.as.ee@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.DefaultInterceptorConfigurator.configure(DefaultInterceptorConfigurator.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Was there any pattern like "JBAS" right after "DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4)" ? 
What's JBoss version?
JBoss warns you when it can't find no-args constructor for a class. It seems that kind of warning.

Comment: I've fixed this by downloading WildFly 20 newly.